# Is there a way to determine if the user selected a shape or a table with PowerPoint VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, selection, shapes

I'm trying to write a PowerPoint macro that would act differently whether the user has selected a PowerPoint table or a "classic" shape (textbox, etc.).

Is there a way to check this with a condition in VBA ?

I've found workarounds using error handling, but I guess there is a proper way to do it.

Any help appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
Sub TableOrShape()
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).HasTable Then
        MsgBox "It's a table!"
    ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).HasTextFrame Then
        MsgBox "It's a text box!"
    End If
End Sub
```